# How to find which Image Button has been pressed when using Server Validate

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a Validate method that looks like this

```
protected void ValidateHello(Object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     //Validate Stuff
}
```

In my ASP I have this line to validate a drop down list.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvNames" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlNames" OnServerValidate="ValidateHello" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please select a Name">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

However I have 2 different imagebuttons. One should have different validation for this drop down box than the other. The only way I can think about doing this is to have an if() statement and check which imagebutton was pressed to cause the validation.

Here is my ImageButton code.

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgSearchNames" CssClass="SearchButton" ImageUrl="~/Images/searchbutton.jpg" OnClick="imgSearchNames_OnClick" ></asp:ImageButton>
```

And this is my OnClick event method.

```
    protected void imgSearchNames_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }
    }
```

Much help is needed and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `validationGroup`.

`ValidationGroup` property makes your inputs to validate only for particular events( `imagebutton_click` let's say) ,

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn" ValidationGroup="xxxx" CausesValidation="true" />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvNames" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="xxxx" OnServerValidate="ValidateHello"  Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please select a Name">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Use same `ValidationGroup` in your `Imagebutton` .
You should also consider using `ValidateEmptyText=true` so that your it will fire validation even for empty controls .